# CSS properties are not used for secondary _Layout C# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: layout, frontend, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I created a website using C# and ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. My current problem is regarding a secondary `_Layout` page.

I tried to create a view called `_Layout_Admin.cshtml` in the folder `Views/Shared/`, in that page I added from bootstrap official page the basic template for html doc, style tags and a navbar. Now in my page where I want to use this Layout I added this and the start of page

```
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Dashboard Administrator";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_Admin.cshtml";
}
```

What happen now, I can see the html elements, but however the CSS properties for those elements is not applied. Did someone meet this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I forget to add those libraries.